# Добавление водяного знака на gif изображение средствами php

Tags: php

Написанный мной код на `php` отлично вставлял водяной знак на изображения. В какой то момент попалось `gif` изображение, и водяной знак вставляется в него очень криво. Изображение, которое получается:
[image]

Но, что самое интересное, с другими форматами работает нормально (`png`, `jpeg`). Я не понимаю, почему вообще такое могло произойти. Вот кусок кода, для изображения в формате gif:

```
<br />
$source_file = imagecreatefromgif($path);
$width = intval($file_info['0']);
$height = intval($file_info['1']);
// ----------- добавление водяного знака -------------------------
if (($width>230)&&($height>60)){
$water_mark = imagecreatefrompng("image/water_mark.png");
imagecopyresampled($source_file, $water_mark, $width-210, $height-55, 0, 0, 200, 45, 200, 45);
}
// ----------- добавление водяного знака -------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gif содержит всего 256 цветов, и когда вы накладываете png в более широкой палитре, то при преобразовании к gif новые цвета попадают в область где содержатся темные цвета палитры gif.

Comment: Это то я и сам догадался. Вопрос - как решить эту проблему. Пробовал перевести изображение из gif в png и потом добавить водяной знак, все равно тот же эффект.

Comment: Вопрос был "Я не понимаю, почему вообще такое могло произойти", а не как это побороть. Попробуйте привести png к палитре gif (imageTrueColorToPalette)

Comment: А можно ли наоборот изображение gif привести к палитре png?

Comment: попробуйте, но не думаю что результат будет положительный, в gif - 256 цветов всего, в png - 16К, лучше делать в меньшую сторону чем в большую.

Comment: Перепробовал все, ни один из вариантов не дает хороших результатов.<br />
Вариант 1)<br />
Перевел png к палитре gif
Результат: от черного цвета избавился, вместо него фон водяного знака стал белым. Это тоже не очень хороший результат, т.к. он не прозрачный, а белый и он закрывает часть картинки.<br />
Вариант 2)<br />
Перевел саму картинку gif в png результат такой же как и в самом начале (фон черный и т.д.)<br />
Вариант 3)<br />
В фотошопе перевел картинку gif в png, и изменил режим цвета. Результат - хороший. Но есть минус - картинок gif очень много, и в ручную переводить не очень хочется

Comment: Наверное во 2 варианте накосячил...

Answer (score 0):

Я там понимаю, у Вас водяной знак - это текст цветной без какого либо фона и дополнительных картинок?
А почему бы тогда просто не "наложить текст" на картинку?

Comment: В данном случае, это выход. Ну это не является решением. Если мне вместо текста нужно будет картинку налепить, то опять эта проблема возникнет.